# Comparing MD5 hash on UIImage on iPhone and file on server

Tags: php, iphone, ios, hash, md5

I am attempting to compute a MD5 hash within an iOS app, in an effort to compare hashes between the file saved within the app and the same file stored on a web server using PHP.

This is the code for the iOS app:

```
unsigned char result[CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];

NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:@"advert.png"];
const void* src = [data bytes];

CC_MD5(src, [data length], result);

    NSString *imageHash = [[NSString stringWithFormat:
                       @"%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X",
                       result[0], result[1], result[2], result[3], 
                       result[4], result[5], result[6], result[7],
                       result[8], result[9], result[10], result[11],
                       result[12], result[13], result[14], result[15]]
                       lowercaseString];

NSLog(@"%@", imageHash);
```

The code for the web server:

```
$file = 'advert.png';
echo 'MD5 file hash of ' . $file . ': ' . md5_file($file);
```

The app generates: D41D8CD98F00B204E9800998ECF8427E

The PHP generates: 3ef9386b1dd50e8e166efbe48f0f9401

md5sum generates:  3ef9386b1dd50e8e166efbe48f0f9401

**UPDATE**:

Just ran the app through the simulator and it correctly computes the hash: 3ef9386b1dd50e8e166efbe48f0f9401.

When ran on my iPhone 4 running iOS 5.1 it calculates as: ddf017003e063e353a5e4ec2cc4a5095

Comment: if you substitute the file for an identical string, do you get the same results?

Comment: Are you able to expand on your answer? Not quite sure what you mean sorry

Comment: currently your getting the hash of a file, i was wondering if there where file over hashing issues; so suggest you just get the hash of a known string.

Comment: Does your carrier compress images?

Comment: @DanSmith, how did you get the app to properly compute the md5sum?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`D41D8CD98F00B204E9800998ECF8427E` is the MD5 sum of an empty file. Your don't read the file correctly, the reason is probably that dataWithContentsOfFile: needs an absolute path.
Try:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"advert" ofType:@"png"];
NSData *plistData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

Comment: I can confirm the image is being read off the device. Using the code above I am able to display the image within the GUI successfully. I am now getting a hash of: ddf017003e063e353a5e4ec2cc4a5095

Comment: Well, then you have a new, different problem. Posting a clear problem description should help a lot in finding a solution.

Comment: I'm still getting used to how to use this site, should I edit my original post?

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that you have just witnessed the iPhone PNG optimizer in action.

Comment: I believe I have.. both generate the hash: 5d41402abc4b2a76b9719d911017c592 for the string 'hello'. So I believe the iOS MD5 code is right, the delivery of the image is not though :P